# How can I add style to the body element with JSS?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, jss, css-in-js

I'm building an application using react-jss to style my components and wanted to know if it is possible to add styles to top-level elements (like `html` or `body`).

To illustrate, I have this simple NotFound component that I'm styling with react-jss. The style works fine, but the problem is the `body` elements has a default margin that I wanted to remove.

NotFound.js

```
import React from 'react';
import injectSheet from 'react-jss';

const styles = {
    notFound: {
        fontFamily: 'Roboto',
        backgroundColor: 'blue',
        color: 'white'
    }
}

function NotFound({ classes }) {
  return (
    <div className={classes.notFound}>
      NOT FOUND
    </div>
  )
}

export default injectSheet(styles)(NotFound);
```

[image]

Does anyone know if its possible to remove this margin using css-in-js? (I wanted to avoid css)

Comment: I would rather recommend you to create a file called `global.css` and put all your global styles there. Later just require it in your index.js and that's all. No need to add another dependency to your project to just add styles to the body element. But it's up to you.

Comment: is there a reason why it have to use injectSheet this way? I have trouble exporting it as non default export.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use the syntax introduced by jss-plugin-global

```
  '@global': {
    body: {...}
  }
```

Also recommend creating a separate component for this and wrap your component with it. Otherwise your specific component becomes less reusable.

Answer (score 2):

Just to elaborate Oleg's response, that's what I did:

1.Create my own JssProvider. **Note:** Had to also add `jss-plugin-camel-case` otherwise it wouldn't parse my properties from `camelCase` to `lisp-case`:

```
import App from './App';
import { create } from 'jss';
import { JssProvider } from 'react-jss';
import globalPlugin from 'jss-global';
import camelCase from 'jss-plugin-camel-case';

const jss = create();
jss.use(globalPlugin(), camelCase());

render(
    <JssProvider jss={jss}>
        <Router>
            <App />
        </Router>
    </JssProvider>
    document.getElementById("app")
);
```

2.Added my global property to my top level component

```
import React from "react";

import Main from "./common/ui/components/Main";
import NotFound from "./components/NotFound";
import injectSheet from 'react-jss';

const style = {
    '@global': {
        body: {
            margin: 0
        }
    }
};

const App = () => {
    return (
        <Main>
            <Switch>
                <Route component={NotFound}/>
            </Switch>
        </Main>
    );
};

export default injectSheet(style)(App);
```

And that was it! Worked like a charm.

**EDIT:** After some more research I found that I don't need step 1. Just adding the `@global` style to my `App` component did the job. I guess this `jss-global` plugin must be default in `react-jss`. (someone correct me if I'm wrong)